# javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong. I am bound to use Form Bean within Form Bean as there are numerous different parts of the form. Basically, there is a response part as well as request part on the same form.

While initializing the view, I am getting a no getter method exception.
I am using `Struts 1.2`

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property getAvailableAddres
sRequest.resellerId of bean org.apache.struts.taglib.html.BEAN
    at org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.lookup(RequestUtils.java:968)
```

struts-config.xml:

```
<form-beans>
        <form-bean name="getAvailableAddress" type="com.wisor.talktalk.model.GetAvailableAddress" />
        <form-bean name="provideRequest" type="com.wisor.talktalk.common.talktalkbean.RequestActionForm" />
    </form-beans>

    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/ttTestJsp" type="com.wisor.talktalk.controller.TestJsp" 
            name="getAvailableAddress" 
            scope="session" 
            validate="false" 
            unknown="false">
            <forward name="init" path="/WEB-INF/talk/preorderView/getAvailableAddress.jsp"/>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
```

JSP Page:

```
<html:form action="/ttTestJsp.do?task=getResponse" styleClass="form">
        <fieldset>
            <label class="inline label" for="reseller_id"><fmt:message
                    key="label.field.resellerId" />:</label>
            <html:text
                property="getAvailableAddressRequest.resellerId"
                styleClass="mandatory" readonly="readonly"></html:text>
        </fieldset>
    <html:submit value="GetAddress"/>
    </html:form>
```

FormBean Main:

```
public class GetAvailableAddress extends ActionForm{
    private GetAvailableAddressRequest getAvailableAddressRequest;

    public void intilize(){
        getAvailableAddressRequest = new GetAvailableAddressRequest();
    }

    public GetAvailableAddressRequest getGetAvailableAddressRequest(){
        return this.getAvailableAddressRequest;
    }

    public void setGetAvailableAddressRequest(GetAvailableAddressRequest getAvailableAddressRequest){
        this.getAvailableAddressRequest = getAvailableAddressRequest;
    }
}
```

child Form Bean:

```
public class GetAvailableAddressRequest implements Serializable{

    private String resellerId;

    public String getResellerID(){
        return this.resellerId;
    }
    public void setResellerID(String resellerId){
        this.resellerId = resellerId;
    }
}
```

Action Class:

```
public class TestJsp extends Action {
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
@Override
public ActionForward execute( ActionMapping map, ActionForm actionForm,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{
ActionForward forward = null;
        GetAvailableAddress form = (GetAvailableAddress) actionForm;
form.intilize();
forward = map.findForward("init");
        return forward;
}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your getter and setter for ressellerId field are not properly named in GetAvailableAddressRequest class. You are using ID at the end of the method name instead of Id
Corrected signatures below:

```
   public String getResellerId(){
        return this.resellerId;
    }
    public void setResellerId(String resellerId){
        this.resellerId = resellerId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the property name of the input tag must match with a getter method name in the action form

sample :
in the jsp

```
<html:textarea property="productDescription" rows="15" cols="50" >
</html:textarea>
```

in the action form

```
public String getProductDescription() {
    return productDescription;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To others being redirected here: first check all your variable/method names.

The problem for me was that the Form Bean requested the values from the POJO class(the class with getters and setters) in order to display the initial jsp; since they had no value to begin with, they returned a null, making the jsp think there's no getter.

Just set a default value, even "".

```
public class GetAvailableAddressRequest implements Serializable{

//private String resellerId;
private String resellerId = "defaultValue";

public String getResellerID(){
    return this.resellerId;
}
public void setResellerID(String resellerId){
    this.resellerId = resellerId;
}
```

This fixed it for me!

Answer (score -1):

your getter and setter for this field are not properly named in.
it should be like "private String variableName" not like "private String VariableName".
CamelCase is not recommended here.